# configure devise for "real email sending"?

Tags: configuration, ruby-on-rails-3.1, devise

I need to know how configure the gem devise,Im using ruby 1.9.2, rails 3.1.3, devise 1.5.3, Im making an app about surveys, and im creating my "authentication module",  in my log file I can see that the user receive the email for activate the account, when I copy the link (from the log file) to activate the account it works, but in this moment I can't test it "really", because don't receive a "real email" about activate the account in my gmail (I fill the form with my own information) I just can see it in my log file...so my question is: how can configure devise in production mode? which are the commands? (basic) step by step...Im a beginner...thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have a look at the guides:

```
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
  :address              => "smtp.gmail.com",
  :port                 => 587,
  :domain               => 'baci.lindsaar.net',
  :user_name            => '<username>',
  :password             => '<password>',
  :authentication       => 'plain',
  :enable_starttls_auto => true  }
```

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html#action-mailer-configuration-for-gmail

EDIT

this configuration would need to go into the `config/environments/development.rb` if you want that in development environment. see the guides about configuring your application: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html

Comment: thanks...but as I said...Im a beginner...so...in what file paste this code...sorry...